# Why does running sudo cp show two processes

Tags: process, sudo

I am trying to copy some files and folders on a CentOS machine.

I do it like so: `sudo cp source destination &`  to run it in the background.

I see there are three `cp` processes now when I run `ps aux | grep cp`:  One of them is the `grep` command itself, but the other two are copies of the above `cp` command: one with the entire command listed above and the other without the `sudo` in front. The PIDs of the two processes also differs by one.
The owner of both is listed as root.

Why are there two processes?

Comment: You already understand why `grep cp` shows up in the process list. This should explain why `sudo cp` also shows up.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The two processes are `sudo` on the one hand, and `cp` on the other. When you run

```
sudo cp source destination &
```

the shell starts `sudo` with the full command line; then `sudo` (which runs as `root` because it is setuid `root`) checks that you're allowed to run `cp` like that, and forks and starts `cp`. So while `cp` is running you see both `sudo` and `cp` processes.